# Change depth for find when searching directories

Tags: find

I'd like to find all directories containing `.txt` files. But I need to print one level up the output.

For example, I'm using `find` to search recursively for `.txt` files in the current directory. Then only the directories containing such files are shown.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf '%h\n'
```

outputs to (for example)

```
./out/data
./out/data
./output/data
```

So, I'd like to improve the use of `find` to:

1. does not show repeated dirs (I think it happens because there are 2 `.txt` file therein)
2. I'd like to print only the first level, that is, only `./out/` and `./output/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a more `find`-centric way, but you could do it with a couple of other tools helping:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '%h\n' | cut -f1,2 -d/ | sort -u
```

Or I guess we could save a process and use `awk` like

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '%h\n' | awk -F/ '{matched[$1"/"$2]=1} END {for(dir in matched) {print dir}}'
```

Comment: Since I have a lot of files and folders, which command could be faster?

Comment: @Sigur my gut says the second, but I'd have to benchmark them to say for sure

Comment: What do you think about `awk -F'/' '{print $1"/"$2}'`. It is simpler, I think.

Comment: @Sigur it's simpler, but won't remove duplicates

Comment: Actually, I think the first might run faster.  Unless you have really long directory names that only have differences at the end, the `sort` is going to be extremely efficient, and probably better than interpreted `awk`

Comment: @Sigur I did a little experiment and found that @MAP's intuition beats mine, the `cut`/`sort` version ran faster

Comment: Since all my directories start with `output` and then `date time`, they are not different only at the end, so I'll decide to use `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

why not pipe your result to some other tools for further processing, like this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf '%h\n'| sort | uniq | cut -d'/' -f1,2
```

Comment: `sort | uniq` can be combined as `sort -u` which is much more efficient.  And you want to do it after the `cut`, or you still end up with duplicates.

Comment: @MAP you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to keep only the first directory name in the path, then `sort` and keep only the first line of an equal run:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf '%h\n' |
sed -e 's#^\(\./[^/]*\).*#\1#' |
sort -u
```